# XOR and Shifting bits in array

Tags: c++, arrays, xor

I have an array that holds a 16-bit value with each bit in an array index. What I want to do is perform a "bit-wise" XOR of particular array elements and then shift all the elements over by 1 (with wrapping).

In particular, I want to use XOR at the array elements 2, 3, and 5 with last element, 16.

This code is supposed to be cyclic, such that once it has completed a particular number of cycles (65535), it should return to the original input value.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //Initial array input
    int state_array[16] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 };
    int temp[1] = { 0 };

    int array_size = sizeof(state_array) / (sizeof(temp[0]));

    for (int i = 0; i<65535; i++)
    {
        temp[0] = state_array[15];

      //XOR Values
        for (int j = 0; j<16; j++) {
            if ((j == 2 || j == 3 || j == 5) && state_array[15] == 1) {
                state_array[j] = !state_array[j];
            }
        }

        //Shift values
        for (int j = array_size-1; j>0; j--)
        {
            if (j == 0) {
                state_array[0] = temp[0];
            }
            else {
                state_array[j] = state_array[j-1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should happen is that after 65535 iterations, the array returns back to value 0000000000000001, but this does not happen and I cannot figure out why. I feel like its a small, obvious thing I am overlooking in my code but, I can't figure it out.

Comment: The program outputs 0001011111110010. I was printing the result after the XOR and shifting and it seems that there is something wrong in the shifting but im not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're not indexing correctly. Instead of your statement that does the XORing looking like this:

```
if ((j == 2 || j == 3 || j == 5) && state_array[15] == 1) {
    state_array[j] = !state_array[j];
}
```

it needs to be 0-indexed, not 1, and should look like this:

```
if ((j == 1 || j == 2 || j == 4) && state_array[15] == 1) {
    state_array[j] = !state_array[j];
}
```

Ironically, your `state_array[15]` was correct, it's just `2`, `3`, and `5` that need to be fixed.

Additionally, your `for` loop should have the condition `j>=0` not just `j>0`.

Answer (score 1):

In the shift section you will never hit the `j == 0` condition as your for loop condition is `j > 0`

Comment: So how can i change the loop so that i get wrapping? i.e. index 15 should wrap to index 0.

Comment: You should be able to just change the for loop condition to `j >= 0`. Should be safe as far as avoiding falling out of bounds since the else section won't execute in the `j == 0` case.

Comment: Just tried that and it changed my output to 0001010101101100. Different result, but still not correct.

Comment: Additionally, your XOR section doesn't really do what it sounds like you are trying to accomplish. You are just flipping the bits at those locations. XOR operation needs at least 2 inputs.

Comment: The XOR operation is correct since the bit is only flipped if the last bit is high. `A XOR 1 = ~A`

Comment: Ahh, right, misunderstood that part of the problem statement. That makes sense :)